# Testing IntersectionObserver rendering with Jest and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have used IntersectionObserver to lazy load some react components on a page in order to improve performance. In the browser I see the elements load in as I scroll and it functions correctly. The issue I'm having is testing it with Jest. I am updating tests that already exist and now they're failing saying he expected elements cannot be found. I am assuming this is because I would need to scroll in order to make them actually render. I've tried manually using FireEvent.scroll() in order to move the screen but that doesn't work. Below I've attached my IntersectionObserver hook along with a sample test that is failing.

UseIntersection hook:

```
import { useEffect, RefObject } from 'react';
const listenerCallbacks = new Map();

const handleIntersections = (entries : IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    entries.forEach((entry: IntersectionObserverEntry) => {
        if (listenerCallbacks.has(entry.target)) {
            const callback = listenerCallbacks.get(entry.target);

            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                listenerCallbacks.delete(entry.target);
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}

const getIntersectionObserver = () => {
        return new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersections, {
            rootMargin: "0px",
            threshold: 0
        });
    }   

export const useIntersection = (elem: RefObject<Element>, callbackFn: () => void) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const target = elem.current ? elem.current : new Element;
        const currentObserver = getIntersectionObserver();

        listenerCallbacks.set(target, callbackFn);
        currentObserver.observe(target);

        return () => {
            listenerCallbacks.delete(target);
            currentObserver.unobserve(target);
        }
    });
}
```

Example Test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  const mockIntersectionObserver = jest.fn();
  mockIntersectionObserver.mockReturnValue({
    observe: () => null,
    unobserve: () => null,
    disconnect: () => null
  });
  window.IntersectionObserver = mockIntersectionObserver;
});

it("should render cards", async () => {
    renderWithContext(
        <TestPage/>
    );


    // const scrollContainer = screen.getByTestId("scrollableContainer");
    // fireEvent.scroll(scrollContainer, {y: 1000})
    // fireEvent.scroll(window, { target: { scrollY: 10000 } });
    
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(
        screen.getByRole("heading", {
          name: /heading content/i,
        })
      ).toBeInTheDocument()
    );
    expect(screen.getByText("New")).toBeInTheDocument();
    
  });
```

React Component Snippet:

```
const [isInView, setIsInView] = useState(false);
const carouselCardRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  useIntersection(carouselCardRef, () => {
    setIsInView(true);
  });
  
  const card = ( 
    <div
      className={`flex items-center justify-between w-100 h-100 ${
        isCarouselMode ? "" : "mb1 br3 shadow-1"
      }`}
      data-testid="carousel-card"
      ref={carouselCardRef}
      style={{minHeight: "176px"}}
    > {isInView && (
<p>Visible</p>
)}
```

This is what the failing test says: Unable to find role="heading"

This test was passing before I added the observer

I've tried manually using FireEvent.scroll() in order to move the screen but that doesn't work. I also added a mockObserver to my tests but that didn't help either.

Comment: Might be relevant https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/671